# Retrieve the name of the most recent file in a directory using VB.Net

Tags: vb.net

Let's say I am looking for a file that has a name that starts with GLNO1_
I can have hundreds of files that start with those characters, but I want to retrieve the name of the file that starts with those characters that is the most recently modified.

For example, Lets say I have files GLNo1_1, GLNo1_2, GLNo1_3 etc. up to _1000
and number 556 is the file that was modified the most recent.

In VB.Net, how do I retrieve that file name.

The file extensions are of .csv

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll have to enumerate the files and pick the last one.  That's a job for Linq:

```
    Dim dir = New System.IO.DirectoryInfo("c:\foo\bar")
    Dim file = dir.EnumerateFiles("GLNo1_*.csv").
        OrderByDescending(Function(f) f.LastWriteTime).
        FirstOrDefault()
    If file IsNot Nothing Then
        Dim path = file.FullName
        '' etc..
    End If
```

Never overlook the odds that there will be more than one "last one".  If your program hasn't run for a while then more than one file could easily have been added by whatever software generates the *.csv files.  You generally need to keep track of the files you've already seen before.